# how to convert shapefile in gpx route not gpx waypoints

Tags: qgis, shapefile, gps, export

When I do "save as gpx", it creates a gpx file with waypoints only, although I force route and track.
  Besides other non-gpx schema columns all relavant gpx columns exist based on a attribute table merge of a 'gpx to point shapefile' layer and 'custom point shapefile' layer.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: QGIS, version 2.8.15

Comment: I believe that the point layer must have a special structure for making it possible to create the tracks and routes http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpx.html

Comment: is there any example around?

Comment: Did you use the `GPS Tools` icon, or `Save As ...`?

Comment: `Save As...` ==> only waypoints / `GPS Tools -> Import other file` 00> empty files (but chosing _shapefile_ as input file type list all let me select `*.cpg`, `*.dbf`, `*.prj`, `*.shp` and `*.shx`. I tried `*.shp` and `*.dbf`.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpx.html

> Starting with GDAL/OGR 1.8.0, if a layer is named "track_points" with
>   wkbPoint/wkbPoint25D geometries, the tracks in the GPX file will be
>   built from the sequence of features in that layer. This is the way of
>   setting GPX attributes for each track point, in addition to the raw
>   coordinates. Points belonging to the same track are identified thanks
>   to the same value of the 'track_fid' field (and it will be broken into
>   track segments according to the value of the 'track_seg_id' field).
>   They must be written in sequence so that track objects are properly
>   reconstructed. The 'track_name' field can be set on the first track
>   point to fill the  element of the track. **Similarly, if a layer
>   is named "route_points" with wkbPoint/wkbPoint25D geometries, the
>   routes in the GPX file will be built from the sequence of points with
>   the same value of the 'route_fid' field. The 'route_name' field can be
>   set on the first track point to fill the  element of the route.**

You can find from the GDAL autotest suite an example how to create a point layer that can be used for constructing routes. It is a Python script but the idea matters, not the method. See file https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/autotest/ogr/ogr_gpx.py starting from line 436.

```
feat = ogr.Feature(lyr.GetLayerDefn())
geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt('POINT(2 49)')
feat.SetField('route_name', 'ROUTE_NAME')
feat.SetField('route_fid', 0)
feat.SetGeometry(geom)
lyr.CreateFeature(feat)

feat = ogr.Feature(lyr.GetLayerDefn())
geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt('POINT(3 50)')
feat.SetField('route_name', '--ignored--')
feat.SetField('route_fid', 0)
feat.SetGeometry(geom)
lyr.CreateFeature(feat)

feat = ogr.Feature(lyr.GetLayerDefn())
geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt('POINT(3 51)')
feat.SetField('route_name', 'ROUTE_NAME2')
feat.SetField('route_fid', 1)
feat.SetGeometry(geom)
lyr.CreateFeature(feat)

feat = ogr.Feature(lyr.GetLayerDefn())
geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt('POINT(3 49)')
feat.SetField('route_fid', 1)
feat.SetGeometry(geom)
lyr.CreateFeature(feat)
```

You must add an integer attribute "route_fid" into your point layer and insert the same number for all points which belong to the same route. If you want to give a name for your route, insert also a string attribute "route_name". If you can't manage to do the conversion with QGIS have a try with GDAL

```
ogr2ogr -f gpx my_route.gpx my_points_with_route_fids.shp
```

Comment: is there any example for QGIS around otherwise it will quite and trial and error thing. I'm not familiar with GDAL.

Comment: Try with QGIS then. Add field "route_id" and see what happens. QGIS does quite many things internally with GDAL.